# What is aHa^1 in relation to a subgroup H and a group G?

Tags: abstract-algebra

[Subgroups and Groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suPwk.png)

I am not looking for the proof. I am looking as to what aHa^-1 actually is. Is it a subgroup of the subgroup H or is it a value that H spits out?

Comment: It is a set of elements of $G$, as described in the link.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange.

Comment: What do you mean welcome to stackexchange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition,

$$aHa^{-1}=\left\{aha^{-1}:h\in H\right\},$$

that is, it is a set.

Comment: right, and that it is a subgroup depends on the subgroup criterion. So does aHa^-1 produce a value? If h is in H and H = Z, and we picked h =1 and a=2, wouldn't aha^1 = 1?\

Comment: No, it's always a subgroup (not by definition, but it's not too difficult to show). $H$ being normal means that the subgroup $aHa^{-1}$ is actually $H$ no matter which $a$ you choose.

Comment: So by proving aHa^-1 is a subgroup using the subgroup criteria, you always prove H is a subgroup of G no matter what a is. I see.

Comment: Also just a note: By saying a is an element of G, does that imply that a is in H and therefore H is nonempty?

Comment: @IbrahimChalhoub $H$ is defined as a subgroup of $G$, and all groups are non-empty. But no, it doesn't imply $a\in H$.

Answer (score 1):

The set $aHa^{-1} = \{aha^{-1}: h \in H\}$ is the image of $H$ under the isomorphism: $\varphi_a:G \to G$ defined by $\varphi_a(g) = aga^{-1}$. It is another subgroup of $G$ that has the same size as $H$ and has many of the same properties as $H$.

This set is a very important set in group theory (e.g. see [Steven Roman's exposition on normal subgroups](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7exk-zI2-3g) for a longer discussion of this and normal subgroups which are exactly the subgroups that "look the same" after changing variables using any conjugation), but intuitively it is like a "change of variables" on the group. For example, when you are looking at a collection of matrices $H$ and change of basis matrix $P$, the collection of matrices of $H$ after a change of variables is: $PHP^{-1} = \{PAP^{-1}: A \in H\}$. 
In general, when you have a group automorphism (a map $\varphi: G \to G$ that is a group homomorpism and has an inverse) then that gives a change of variables. The change of variables given by conjugation are called inner automorphisms (they have inverse $\varphi_{a^{-1}}: g \mapsto a^{-1}ga$).

For example, if you look at the group $D_4 = \langle r, \rho | r^2 = 1, \rho^{4} = 1, r\rho = \rho^{-1}r\rangle $ the symmetries of the square with $r$ being a horizontal reflection and $\rho$ being a quarter counter-clockwise turn. If you look at the subgroup $H = \{1, r\}$ of horizonatal reflection and the identity, then if you look at the subgroup $$\rho H \rho^{-1} = \{\rho r \rho^{-1}, \rho 1 \rho^{-1}\} = \{\rho^2 r, 1\}$$
you see that this is the vertical reflections (make a little square and check this.)

Likewise, if we consider the subgroup $H' = \{1, \rho, \rho^2, \rho^3\}$ of all rotations, we see that conjugation by any element $a$ of $D_4$ does not change $H'$ (you can check this... please do if you are not too familiar with this... or just use that $[D_4, H] = 2$ which implies that $H$ is normal.)

Answer (score 0):

$aHa^{-1}$ is a conjugate of $H$ by an element $a$ of $G$. It's neccessarily a subgroup of $G$, but that's not true in $H$. First of all it should be hard to prove that $H$ and $aHa^{-1}$ have the same order and hence if $aHa^{-1} \le H$, then we must have $aHa^{-1} = H$, i.e. $H$ is a normal subgroup of G.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever $H$ is a *subset* of a group $G$ and $a$ is an element of $G$ then $aHa^{-1}$ is also a *subset* of $G$: all the elements $aha^{-1}$ for $ a \in H$.

If $H$ happens to be a *subgroup* then for any particular $a$ so is $aHa^{-1}$. (You should be able to prove that using the definition of subgroup).

Sometimes $aHa^{-1}$ is actually the same set as $H$ whatever $a$ you try, but rearranged by the function $a \to aha^{-1}$.

You should work out some examples. The six element group of permutations of three things (the group of symmetries of a triangle) is a good place to start.